# CSS how to change page content depending on page size (zoom) in responsive design

Tags: css

I'm pretty familiar with responsive design and how to give the elements relative width .. my question is  how the page turns from
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS6qo.png)to [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuRlr.png) thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to learn the @media rule. [@media on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) 
You do not need to use any jquery. All responsive design can be completed using css.

W3Schools says "The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices."

Basically @media is an if statement that says 'if the screen size is 480px wide use these styles.

Comment: oh Thanks a lot .. it can't be done using Bootstrap ?

Comment: Yes bootstrap has these functions built in.